# After packaging chaincode, install command giving error reading as gzip stream: gzip: invalid header

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

> Hyperledger-Fabric V2.3.x
>
> Peer V2.3.3
>
> Go V1.16

Full Error:

`Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not parse as a chaincode install package: error reading as gzip stream: gzip: invalid header`

My Setup:

```
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=./crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt

CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=./crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp

ORDERER_CA=./crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem

CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
```

Previously invoked command (Successfull):

`peer chaincode package mycc.tar.gz -p . -n mycc --lang golang -v 1.0`

Command (for which I got error):

`peer lifecycle chaincode install mycc.tar.gz`

**Please comment if any other information required*

---

go.mod (used to install dependecies)

```
module github.com/chaincode

go 1.16

require (
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.2 // indirect
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go v0.0.0-20200424173110-d7076418f212 // indirect
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go v1.1.0
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go v0.0.0-20200424173316-dd554ba3746e // indirect
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.5.1 // indirect
    golang.org/x/tools v0.1.7 // indirect
)
```

chaincode.go (few lines)

```
package chaincode

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go/contractapi"
)

// SmartContract provides functions for managing an Asset
type SmartContract struct {
    contractapi.Contract
}

// Asset describes basic details of what makes up a simple asset
//Insert struct field in alphabetic order => to achieve determinism accross languages
// golang keeps the order when marshal to json but doesn't order automatically
type Asset struct {
    AppraisedValue int    `json:"AppraisedValue"`
    Color          string `json:"Color"`
    ID             string `json:"ID"`
    Owner          string `json:"Owner"`
    Size           int    `json:"Size"`
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the packages I installed using command:

`GO111MODULE=on go mod vendor`

I defined wrong version of go 1.14 in "go.mod" instead of 1.16 because the version of go installed was "1.16".

(The incompatible packages were installed, so the package file generated was not a correct gzip file)

Solution:

- Delete vendor folder
- write go.mod with correct go version OR use go init (https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/create-module)
- run `GO111MODULE=on go mod vendor`
- run peer lifecycle package command
- run peer lifecycle install command